# How to preload babel languages in LaTeX format?

Tags: babel

In the good old days, Babel used to provide the list of languages loaded:

```
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for american, french, loaded.
```

After upgrading to TeXLive 2016, I got this:

```
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 2
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 53 language(s) loaded.
```

Now (2018) I get:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded     format=pdflatex 2018.11.10)  10 NOV 2018 13:26
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**smf_ast_403
(./smf_ast_403.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
```

(no mention of babel), and further down:

```
) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2018/10/16 3.26 The Babel package
 (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/10/16 3.26 Babel switching mechanism
)
<*languages>
0   francais    frhyph.tex  
</languages>
```

and I see only one language loaded, namely French, with language ID 0, even though I have called babel by saying

```
\RequirePackage[french,main=english,showlanguages]{babel}
```

Is that ID=0 language loaded in the format?
If yes, how can I load more languages in the format? In the good old days there was a `language.dat` file to do that, but it doesn't seem to be used anymore, or is it?

My document has French hyphenation everywhere although it is in English, how can I systematically have both patterns, the English one at `\language0` and the French one at `\language1` ?

Comment: The mechanism for loading patterns hasn't changed, and `language.dat` is still there. (Well, for some time `lualatex` was based on a different mechanism, now it relies on the old good `language.dat`.) In my system, the languages are correctly loaded, so I perhaps latex is reading a wrong `language.dat`.

Comment: How do I know which `language.dat` is read? When I do a `kpsewhich language.dat`, I get one which has many languages, not just french.  And how do I create the pdflatex format? When I write `pdfetex --ini latex.ltx` I get an error message "LaTeX requires e-TeX"

Comment: Run fmtutil-sys to recreate the formats. https://tug.org/texlive/doc/fmtutil.html

Comment: I think what happened was that tlmgr created format files with the wrong language.dat file, so I had to create them again as this: `pdfetex --ini -etex -output-format=pdf "*latex.ltx";
mv latex.fmt /usr/local/texlive/newest/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`